# Should one use thousands separators in equations?

Tags: equations, delimiters, punctuation

I understand that this is not strictly a TeX question but I have recently been asked to correct an equation presented as the first example in the image below to that of the second example i.e., to use the thousands separator. I compromised by typesetting the third example with a `\thinspace` as the thousands separator.

[image]

All three types are allowed in SI units. What would you recommend? Is there a canonical way?

**Edit**

I came across a [paper](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/papers/jfsp.tex.gz) by Knuth, where large number coefficients are used.

[image]

He clearly is in favour of not using any separators or spaces. This fact, besides his own papers is corroborated by an anecdote described in  [Mathematical Writing (page 53)](http://tex.loria.fr/typographie/mathwriting.pdf), regarding an article he submitted to the ACM.

> [...] where Don wrote 1000000 they
>   substituted 1,000,000. Don objected
>   that although this might be justifed
>   in text, his use is perfectly OK in a
>   formula. Well then, they replied,
>   write 10<sup>6</sup> Fine, said, Don,
>   but what do I do  when the number is
>   1234567? The IEEE standard here is to
>   insert spaces, thus: 1 234 567. Don
>   doesn't like this in formulae, but
>   agrees that it may be useful in a high
>   precision context, such as numerical
>   tables.

For me that settles it!

Comment: from mathematical typesetting completely without additional space.

Comment: @Herbert Traditionally we would not separate them, hence my choice. The counter-argument was that there is no valid reason not to and that it improves readability.  Steven G. Krantz in Handbook of Typography for the Mathematical Sciences is silent about this.

Comment: Are you using the `\num` macro from the `siunitx` package?

Comment: If you were to go for the middle version (commas), at least use `{,}` rather than the bare comma. That will fix the rather glaring problem with spacing. Personally, I lean toward the thin space solution, even in mathematics, at least if the numbers have nine digits or more. But I might be tempted to break with tradition and put them in groups of five rather than three.

Comment: @Yannis: you want to show an approximation of a function, the reason why it is not important for the reader how large a number may be, important is only how the number is build; the definition of erf^{-1} as a sum is more of interest to the reader

Comment: Looking through the maths course I'm currently doing (OU M373: Optimisation), large numbers are divided up in SI style `0.123 456`, with what look like thin spaces. However, that is in tables rather than in equations, at least that I've found so far.

Comment: In french, we use a thin space, I get it with \numprint{...} or \np{...} with the package numprint.sty. numprint works with babel.

Comment: @Harald Would you please put your comment in an answer? I would like to accept it.

Comment: @Yiannis: Sure.

Comment: @Herbert: I agree; numbers with that many significant digits should only be used for measurements or numerical results. The number 182476800 is quite insignificant in this case, it is more interesting how it is calculated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74353/what-commands-are-there-for-horizontal-spacing)

Comment: @ColeJohnson Huh? Not really and how can you this is a duplicate of a question asked one year later than this one? Why not the other way round.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you were to go for the middle version (commas), at least use {,} rather than the bare comma. That will fix the rather glaring problem with spacing. Personally, I lean toward the thin space solution, even in mathematics, at least if the numbers have nine digits or more. But I might be tempted to break with tradition and put them in groups of five rather than three.

Answer (score 6):

Your question rely upon your country's mathematics typesetting triditional habbit, and it is not a TEX problem. Anyway, You could input

```
\frac{\pi^2}{123\thousandsymbol 456}
```

to get diffrence output easily.
If your codes had been finished, the better way (as far as I know) to modify them is using regular expression, adding the command inside digits (on reverse order).

Comment: If it is needed, `numprint` or `siunitx` may be a better choice.

Comment: You're right. I hadn't read the ealier comments yet before i submitted.