# Beyond Bringhurst: mathematical typesetting

Tags: math-mode, typography, books

I've been reading *The Elements of Typographic Style* and I was wondering whether there was a similar resource for specifically *mathematical* typesetting.

Is there a book or other document that sets out answers to the following questions:
 - What are the basic units of mathematical writing and how much space should there be between each of them? 
 - What fonts are available that contain a good selection of specially designed mathematical symbols (Sum and integral symbols; Greek letters that fit with the italic and roman alphabets; arrows, primes, etc. that fit with the typeface)
 - Advice on when inline maths is appropriate and when formulae should be on a new line.

Ideally something that deals with these questions with an eye to TeX and friends, but I'm really looking for something on *typography*. N.B. I'm not really looking for answers to the above questions here, but for resources that offer answers to them as part of a systematic treatment of mathematical typesetting in the mould of Bringhurst's *Elements …*

Comment: There's Appendix G of the TeXbook.

Comment: I attempted to do something like that in my book “Tipografía y notaciones científicas” (in Spanish, 2008). If I've succeeded or not, I don't know.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can have a look at Knuth's  [Guide to Mathematical Typography](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/preprints.html#ref), it is a bit different, but consider it as a guide by example. For example it helped me to solve [Should one use thousands separators in equations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9754/should-one-use-thousands-separators-in-equations). (See also  http://tex.loria.fr/typographie/mathwriting.pdf).

P.R Halmo's *How to Write Mathematics* is also good, although not concentrating on typography but more on style and exposition, as he says *This is a subjective essay, and its title is misleading; a more honest title might be 'How I write Mathematics'* . There is a copy [here](http://www.math.uh.edu/~tomforde/Books/Halmos-How-To-Write.pdf).

Comment: Is the link you gave for the Knuth thing correct? Is this what you meant? http://tex.loria.fr/typographie/mathwriting.pdf

Comment: @Seamus They both correct. In the first link, you can download his papers in TeX. He has well thought "samples" for everything! Halmos writing's are also good, I will amend the post.

Comment: If this is the Halmos of _Naïve set theory_ I like his style...

Comment: Yes and the Halmos symbol fame http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halmos_symbol

Comment: @Seamus: Halmos is unique.

Comment: There is also some material by Knuth on typesetting mathematics (and more on the mathematics of typesetting) in a collection of his papers *"Digital Typography", CSLI, 1999*, in particular Chapter 18 *Typesetting Concrete Mathematics* (originally in [TugBoat Issue 10:1](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Contents/contents10-1.html)) and chapter 2 *Mathematical Typography*.

Comment: @mas Thanks a lot for the additional links. There was also a very early paper while TeX was being developed in the AMS, but I couldn't trace it.

Comment: Perhaps later than the one you are thinking of but the *Mathematical Typography* paper in *"Digital Typography"* originally appeared in *Bulletin of the AMS* (new series) 1 (March 1979), pp 337-372 and was a lecture given under the auspices of the AMS on 4 January 1978.

Comment: @mas memory is fading:), this is the one!

Answer (score 21):

*"Handbook of typography for the mathematical sciences"* by Steven Krantz (2001) extended Swanson's *"Mathematics into Type"* into the digital typesetting, specifically TeX, world. Whilst it may not address all your questions in the detail you want it may be helpful to identify specific questions. There is a preview of the  book on [Google books](http://books.google.com/books?id=gjKJhLlgnkQC&hl=en).

A second work, mentioned more for its links to Bringhurst rather than being exclusively mathematical, is the forthcoming (in print, earlier versions were available as downloads) [*LaTeX and Friends* by Marc van Dongen](http://tug.org/books/#dongen). A recent [review on the TUG website](http://tug.org/books/reviews/tb102reviews-ltxfriends.html) includes the following:

> Since *The TeXbook*, many books about TeX discuss not only the 
>   typesetting program, but also other aspects of typographic art and 
>   science, discussing the rules for book design and the best practices. 
>   *LaTeX and Friends* follows this tradition, and Bringhurst’s immortal 
>   *Elements* is one of the most often cited books in the text. The reader 
>   learns many useful typographic facts, such as setting the
>   punctuation  symbols at the border of two types in the brighter type,
>   the spacing in  abbreviations and initials, etc. Many people from the
>   intended audience get  their first exposure to the typography from
>   TeX-related books, and this one  provides a good introduction to the
>   subject.

Answer (score 7):

Typesetting rules for mathematics may depend on the specific field of science, i.e. there may be different standards for math, physics, chemistry, etc.
I discussed some of the issues regarding typesetting rules for mathematical physics in my [EuroTeX 2009 proceedings paper](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-3/tb96vieth.pdf). Please check out the reference sections for links to various examples of standard documents.