# How to punctuate multiline equations?

Tags: equations, line-breaking, typography, punctuation

This might be off topic, yet I wouldn't know where else to ask. I want to keep up with the good habit of punctuating displayed equations. For example I know the comma (`,`) is compulsory in

```
Here, we can reduce \(f\) to a more simple form
\[
    f(t) = \exp{-t_c/t},
\]
where \(t_c\) is called the damping constant.
```

Yet how should I treat multiline equations? Take a look at this

```
The function \(g\) is simply the derivative of \(f\), so
\begin{align*}
    g(t) &= \deriv{f(t)}{t}\\
         &= \frac{t_c}{t^2}\exp{-t_c/t},
\end{align*}
so \(g(t)\) will be smaller than \(f(t)\) for large \(t\).
```

is this correctly punctuated?

Comment: I think that punctuation in equations is only confusing. Avoid it!

Comment: Imho, your multi-line equation is correctly punctuated because the second line follows directly from the first. A piece-wise defined function (for example), would warrant commas at the end of each line.

Comment: @N.N. Wait til Knuth puts on his boxing gloves.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mathematics are just symbolic sentences. Punctuate them as you would verbal ones. You can find some resources [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32018/963). Read your maths aloud. If they sound ungrammatical you need to rewrite them. Your first example would read better as:

If we call `t_c`  the damping constant, we can reduce `f` to the simple form `f(t) = \exp{-t_c/t}`.

And the punctuation would automatically make sense.

Answer (score 7):

Although this may be negligible you might wish to consider removing the horizontal spacing added through proper punctuation within a display equation (by using `\rlap`). For example, you could use

```
The function \(g\) is simply the derivative of \(f\), so
\begin{align*}
  g(t) &= \deriv{f(t)}{t}\\
       &= \frac{t_c}{t^2}\exp{-t_c/t}\rlap{,}
\end{align*}
so \(g(t)\) will be smaller than \(f(t)\) for large \(t\).
```

to make sure that the widest stretch of `align*` is centered within the text block.

Comment: wow, TeX for the really sensitive. I do use slap etc a lot to fix other stuff, but this haha. Correct is correct I guess ;)

Comment: Rather than writing `\rlap{,}` I'd write `\,,`. I cannot remember where I saw this advice before, but I've been using it ever since and it looks very good.

Comment: @romeovs: It is what it is. The `align` environment makes no distinction between the "math" and "text" components of its contents.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: Sure, and you could even use `\rlap{\,,}`, since [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) redefines `\,` to be "math and text sensitive", allowing its use in math or text mode; `\rlap` forces the latter.