# Parskip messes up vertical spaces

Tags: parskip

Because of a previous question of mine regarding [how can someone  typeset a mathematical document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208021/right-way-to-typeset-a-mathematical-document) I understood that the best way is to make every customization globally. Having tried it I think that this is indeed the best way. But I have a problem with `parskip` package. When I try to change the vertical space between the paragraphs automatically also changes the vertical space between the `hline` and the paragraph below it (under sections, subsections etc I use `\hline` to separate the title from the text below it) and also the space between the items in an `itemize` environment. I have not yet tried it extensively so I can only guess that there would be more undesirable side-effects. I have found a lot of similar questions regarding environments like itemize but not how to prevent `parskip` mess up every other vertical space. How can I make the changes in `parskip` not to affect other spaces rather than the space between two paragraphs?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage
[
  top=0.7in,
  bottom=1.2in,
  left=0.8in,
  right=0.8in
]{geometry}

%=================================================
%=================================================

\usepackage{parskip}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

%=================================================
%=================================================

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

%Package unicode-math loads fontspec too

%=================================================
%=================================================

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\setmainfont
[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*,
  BoldFont=*Bold,
  ItalicFont=*It,
  BoldItalicFont=*BoldIt,
  Mapping=tex-text
]{GFSArtemisia}

\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSArtemisia.otf}


%Math fonts

\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\varnothing]{Asana-Math.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\int]{latinmodern-math.otf}

\newcommand{\srr}
{
\hrule

\vspace{1cm}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Θεωρία Συνόλων}

\srr

Για τις πράξεις ανάμεσα σε ενδεχόμενα ισχύουν:

\begin{itemize}
\item η αντιμεταθετική
\item η προσεταιριστική
\item η επιμεριστική
\end{itemize}

Θεωρούμε ότι έχουμε $n$ ενδεχόμενα.

Η ένωση τους είναι ένα ενδεχόμενο που εμφανίζεται όταν εμφανιστεί τουλάχιστον ένα από αυτά.

Η τομή τους είναι ένα ενδεχόμενο που εμφανίζεται όταν εμφανιστούν όλα μαζί.

Ασυμβίβαστα ανά δύο ονομάζονται $n$ ενδεχόμενα όταν η εμφάνιση του ενός αποκλείει την εμφάνιση οποιουδήποτε άλλου:
\begin{equation}
A_{i}\cap A_{j}=\varnothing
\end{equation}

\subsection{Κανόνες De Morgan}

\srr

Οι κανόνες De Morgan είναι:
\begin{align}
(A\cup B)'&=A'\cap B'\\
(A\cap B)'&=A'\cup B'
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't put spaces between paragraphs. It's bad for your health and sometimes typography (always).

Comment: And ***don't*** say `\everymath{\displaystyle}`. I'll tell you this every time I'll see the wrong instruction.

Comment: @egreg I am sorry and I know that I have been warned against it far too many times but I just like it. I may in the future abolish it and I am sure that I will if I write something to be published but now these are just personal notes. Also because I mostly write notes I need spaces between paragraphs and these can only be achieved "correctly" by `parskip`.

Comment: remove all the `\srr` and (if you want underlined section titles) redefine the section format to put them in (while compensating for any positive value of `\parskip`) `secsty` package can help with section heading formatting.

Comment: and don't say `\everymath{\displaystyle}` you'll upset @egreg and hurt the eyes of any readers of the document:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle hahaha I will remove it because of this comment! I will use this package for the heading but isn't going to be still a problem with the space between it and the text below? Not to mention all the other extra spaces in the document.

Comment: You can also use a class or package from KOMA-Script (like `scrartcl`) which, apart from lots of nice features, gives you the key `parskip=half` or `parskip=full` (it can be passed as an option to `\documentclass` or as an argument to `\KOMAoptions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like spacing and font choices, the design of an underlined section head is part of the document design so should be in the definition of `\section` not added by hand in each section of the document.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage
[
  top=0.7in,
  bottom=1.2in,
  left=0.8in,
  right=0.8in
]{geometry}

%=================================================
%=================================================

\usepackage{parskip}

\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\zzline}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries\zzline}}

\newcommand\zzline[1]{%
#1\par\hrule}
\makeatother

%=================================================
%=================================================

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

%Package unicode-math loads fontspec too



%=================================================
%=================================================

\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\setmainfont
[
  Ligatures=TeX,
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*,
  BoldFont=*Bold,
  ItalicFont=*It,
  BoldItalicFont=*BoldIt,
  Mapping=tex-text
]{GFSArtemisia}

\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFSArtemisia.otf}


%Math fonts

\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\varnothing]{Asana-Math.otf}
\setmathfont[range=\int]{latinmodern-math.otf}


\begin{document}

\section{Θεωρία Συνόλων}



Για τις πράξεις ανάμεσα σε ενδεχόμενα ισχύουν:

\begin{itemize}
\item η αντιμεταθετική
\item η προσεταιριστική
\item η επιμεριστική
\end{itemize}

Θεωρούμε ότι έχουμε $n$ ενδεχόμενα.

Η ένωση τους είναι ένα ενδεχόμενο που εμφανίζεται όταν εμφανιστεί τουλάχιστον ένα από αυτά.

Η τομή τους είναι ένα ενδεχόμενο που εμφανίζεται όταν εμφανιστούν όλα μαζί.

Ασυμβίβαστα ανά δύο ονομάζονται $n$ ενδεχόμενα όταν η εμφάνιση του ενός αποκλείει την εμφάνιση οποιουδήποτε άλλου:
\begin{equation}
A_{i}\cap A_{j}=\varnothing
\end{equation}

\subsection{Κανόνες De Morgan}



Οι κανόνες De Morgan είναι:
\begin{align}
(A\cup B)'&=A'\cap B'\\
(A\cap B)'&=A'\cup B'
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much I already used your code but that doesn't address the problem that I state with my question regarding the spaces under the lines or inside environments etc. :)

Comment: well it allows you to control the space under the lines which is the 1.5ex.. you can reduce that to compensate for parskip if that's what you want. look at `texdoc parskip` you'll see it admits that it only changes so much (less than I remembered perhaps) and correctly points out that a more complete approach is to design the class from scratch with separated paragraphs in mind, either the ntg classes or koma (ntg is  closer to `article` so is usually a simple change from `article` to `artikel3` koma's classes are more extensive but also offer this functionality as mentioned in comments

Comment: Why `parskip` changes everything? Isn't it used only to change the space between paragraphs? I mean ok someone can say that the space between lines and text is covered by the definition of `parskip` but the space between items is completely irrelevant! I can only guess that this will also mess up the space between tables, images and so on...

Comment: @Adam almost everything is a paragraph internally

Comment: So when I want to just take notes when reading and need to write some text which obviously needs to be separated by a relatively large space between it as it consists of different sentences (it is not a text with a beginning and an end but just random notes to remember what I read) I must use `parskip` that messes up with everything? It just seems far too complicated. I thought that it would be easy to just define what spaces you want, what lines you want and where you want them. I am just confused that's all :P :)

Comment: @Adam try artikel3 instead of article, or if it's just notes and you want it spaced out use article increase \parskip and just let the spaces increase, really anything is better than putting \vspace everywhere, it makes that tex code basically unusable for anything other than that one use.

Comment: Ok thank you for your time. I appreciate it.