# Reformat the mathematical product sign

Tags: math-mode

I'm pretty sure there is a simple formatting solution to this, I just can't find it anywhere.
I'll describe what I want to achieve with the code and the picture.

In my last post I was told to add code to my posts, to make it easier for others to help, so there it the relevant part:

```
\underline{Definition}: A \textbf{state} (or equivalently, an \textbf{instance})  of a database,
is a\\function $f:\Phi\rightarrow \prod_{D\in \mathbb{D}}D$.
Intuitively, $f$ takes a relation name $\phi\in \Phi$ and gives
it an interpretation as a table.
```

Which produces this:

[image]

Notice how the symbol `D\in\mathbb{D}` does not sit right under the `\prod` symbol as I intend.
It does sit there when I wrap it with double `$$`, but it also places the mathematical expression and basically ruins everything...:

[image]

and that's not something I want...

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What is does here is *the right* way to do it. if `$\prod_x$` writes `x` under the `\prod` then it messes up the line spacing making the doc look ugly and unprofessional. So leave LaTeX to do its thing. BTW: you might want to use a better defind for your definition. Noone use underlining anymore.

Comment: So how do you suggest to reformat the definition?

Comment: I think @daleif is suggesting leaving it as it, which is the correct way to present the limits "inline". If you wanted to see the ugliness of the alternative, add the macro `\displaystyle` prior to the `\prod`.  It would make the `\prod` look the way you ask, but screw up the line spacing in the process.

Comment: "so there it the relevant part:" posting fragments is very rarely helpful, it is always better to post a document so people can run the code. although in this case I agree with the previous commenters that  you are best not to change the way inline subscripts are set.

Comment: p.s. If you want one of your comments to be directed "at" a particular user (so that they receive an alert that you left them a comment), include their username preceded by the `@` symbol somewhere in you comment, as in this way:  @so.very.tired

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Not `\displaystyle`, but `\prod\limits_{D\in\mathbb{D}}`; the result will be slightly less horrible.

Comment: @David Carlisle the document is quite big, and I don't see any good reason to post the whole thing.

Comment: @so.very.tired, that is why it is called *minimal*, you take a copy of your document, remove what is irrelevant, and post that.

Comment: some guidance on "professional" formatting of mathematics is given with the question [Right way to typeset a mathematical document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/208021/579).  the current edition of the chicago manual of style also contains recognized guidelines.

Comment: Just a somewhat related comment: I would put `\newcommand*\map[3]{#1\colon#2\to#3}` in the preamble and then use `\map{a}{\Phi}{\prod_{D\in\mathbb{D}}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `nccmath` package and its `\medop` command (medium-sized operator, ~ 80 % of display style) You can have the index under the product symbol if you insert a new paragraph afterwards. Here are two ways of doing things. I use  an unnumbered `definition` environment with the label in small caps, with the `ntheorem` package. Underlining titles dates back to the times of typewriters…

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\setlength\parindent{1em}
\usepackage[thmmarks, amsmath, thref]{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\scshape}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremseparator{:}
\newtheorem{Def}{Definition}
\begin{document}

\begin{Def}
 A \textbf{state} (or equivalently, an \textbf{instance}) of a database, is a function $f \colon \Phi \longrightarrow \medop\prod  \limits _{D \in \mathbb{D}}D$.

Intuitively, $f$ takes a relation name $\phi \in \Phi$ and gives it an interpretation as a table.\end{Def}

\begin{Def}
 A \textbf{state} (or equivalently, an \textbf{instance}) of a database,is a function $f \colon \Phi \longrightarrow \medop\prod  _{D \in \mathbb{D}}D$. Intuitively, $f$ takes a relation name $\phi \in \Phi$ and gives it an interpretation as a table.\end{Def}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think that if you really want to (or need to) to place the limit term (`D\in\mathbb{D}}`) *below* the product symbol and thereby give it a lot of visual prominence, you  should definitely go "all the way" and place the *entire* math expression on a line by itself, in display-math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb} % for \mathbb macro
\setlength\textwidth{8cm} % just for this example
\begin{document}
\noindent
\underline{Definition}: A \textbf{state} (or equivalently, an \textbf{instance})  of a database is a function
\[f\colon\Phi\rightarrow \prod_{D\in \mathbb{D}}D\,.\]
Intuitively, $f$ takes a relation name $\phi\in \Phi$ and gives it an interpretation as a table.
\end{document}
```