# Siunitx does not format numbers

Tags: siunitx

This is my code for the table, I was expecting siunitx to add the comma to the numebers with more than 3 digits, i.e., 3456 -> 3,456 but it does not happen, the numebers without decimals are shown as they are. I tried some code found in answers in this site that works for people but not for me. Any help?

```
 \usepackage{siunitx}
 \sisetup{group-separator={,},group-minimum-digits={3},output-decimal-marker={.}}

  \begin{table}
   \centerfloat
   \caption{Descriptive statistics of Expedia and Tripadvisor datasets.}
   \label{tab:stats}
  \scalebox{1}{
  \begin{tabular}{l S S}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Statistics}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Tripadvisor} &\multicolumn{1}{c}             {Expedia} \\
\hline
Total Hotels & 5356 & 3701 \\
[1em]
Average Reviews per Hotel & 68.3 & 154.93 \\
[1em]
Average Review Length & 665.4 & 210.23 \\
[1em]
Average Review Rating & 3.9 & 4.0 \\
[1em]
Average Hotel Review Rating & 3.6 & 3.9 \\
[1em]
Total Responses & 102564 & 13123 \\
[1em]
Average Response per Hotel & 22.3 & 3.9 \\
[1em]
Average Response Length & 397.8 & 251.3 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\caption*{}
\end{table}
```

enter code here

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: The `siunitx`-package will only format numbers in the `\num{}`-command.

Comment: this is not what I understood. For example here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121387/usepackagegroup-separator-siunitx-not-working-with-longtable look at the first answer. That is what I want but the example does not work for me.

Comment: This is 'works for me': can you add `\listfiles` to your input and report the version information this adds to your `.log` file?

Comment: @user63979: I stand corrected. I just tried compiling your document, and your current code seems to work on my machine (at least in the `memoir` document class).