# Making large numbers readable by inserting thinspaces for visual grouping

Tags: formatting

I prefer a large number be shown in three digit groups. For example `1234567` be shown like `1 234 567`.

Is there a way to make this automatic in `LaTeX` such that wherever I insert `1234567`, it is automatically shown as `1 234 567` in the output?

Comment: Related: [How to typeset large numbers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15911/5764)

Comment: They are good ansers but I'm looking for a more automatic way. For example, with a single command applied to all of the document.

Comment: Look again you'll find the `automatically` word there. I just tried to improve it grammatically. The answers are good, btw they don't solve my problem. So I haven't accepted them yet.

Comment: Are the large numbers in your document integers, or can they contain decimal parts, as in `123456.789012`? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico They are mostly integers. Some of them have decimal part. The decimal part should remain unchanged. But I have no problem if both decimal and integer parts remain unchanged.

Comment: @user62181 - I've updated my answer to (a) not added whitespace grouping to any decimal portions of numbers and (b) not do any processing if the numbers happen to occur in verbatim-like environments.

Comment: @Mico Thanks but I cannot run luatex. Even sharetex.com fails to compile it. Btw, it is hopeful that there is a single command changing everything in luatex.

Comment: See also this posting, from April 2012: [Automatic thousands separators?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50478/5001)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution, which adds thinspaces automatically to the integer parts of numbers that contain between 5 and 12 digits.

Some comments:

- Numbers with exactly four digits do *not* get a thinspace inserted after the first (left-most) digit, in keeping with the comment @egreg posted. If you *do* want a thinspace separator for numbers with exactly four digits, change the final `string.gsub` instruction line from

  ```
              text = string.gsub ( text , "(%d?%d%d)(%d%d%d)", "%1\\,%2" )
  ```

  to

  ```
              text = string.gsub ( text , "(%d?%d?%d)(%d%d%d)", "%1\\,%2" )
  ```
- No thinspaces are inserted in the *decimal portions* of any long numbers; only the integer portions are processed.
- The code keeps track of whether or not we are inside a `verbatim` or `Verbatim` environment. If we're inside such an environment, processing is suspended.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
ok_to_process = true
function ez_read ( line )
  if string.find ( line , "\\begin{[vV]erbatim}" ) then
     ok_to_process = false
     return line
  elseif string.find ( line , "\\end{[vV]erbatim}" ) then
     ok_to_process = true
     return line
  else
    if ok_to_process then
      x = line:gsub ( "([%.]-)(%d+)", function ( back, text )
        if back ~= "" then
          return back..text
        end
        text = string.gsub ( text , "(%d?%d?%d)(%d%d%d)(%d%d%d)(%d%d%d)",
                                    "%1\\,%2\\,%3\\,%4" )
        text = string.gsub ( text , "(%d?%d?%d)(%d%d%d)(%d%d%d)",
                                    "%1\\,%2\\,%3" )
        text = string.gsub ( text , "(%d?%d%d)(%d%d%d)", "%1\\,%2" )
        return text
      end)
      return x
    end
  end
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback( "process_input_buffer", ez_read, "ez_read")
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}    
123456789012, 123456789, 123456, 12345

But: 1234 --- no thinspace after ``1''

123456.123456789, 0.12345, 123456
\end{document}
```

Comment: Usually one doesn't want the separation in groups of four digits (except in tables where separation involves larger groups in the same column).

Answer (score 35):

The packages `numprint` and `siunitx` can do this (here I show `numprint`)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{numprint}

\begin{document}
\numprint{1234567}

\numprint{123456789}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah ha. Improving on your typing speed? `;-)`

Comment: @HarishKumar: Stock answer:-P

Answer (score 23):

`siunitx` provides `\num` macro for such jobs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
  \num{1234567}
\end{document}
```

[image]